# Extracting street names with OSM filter and converter

Tags: openstreetmap

im using [argentina-latest.osm](http://download.geofabrik.de/south-america/argentina.html) and im trying to extract all the streets in a state for example:

```
    osmfilter argentina-latest.osm --keep="addr:state=Neuquen and 
addr:city= and addr:street=" --ignore-depemdencies --drop-relations --
drop-ways |osmconvert - --csv="@oname @id @lon @lat addr:state addr:city 
addr:street"
```

But im getting just a few number of them. Is this a bad way to extract them ?

Comment: I wonder how your command worked at all. `--ignore-depemdencies` contains a typo and must read `--ignore-dependencies` instead.

Comment: Are you sure your ways really have an `addr:state` tag?

Comment: @mmd yes i have, it returns the state. Even if i remove it i still getting only like... 20 streets or less.

Answer (score 0):

it's counterintuitive, but "highway" actually includes all sorts of streets, [see the OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway)

```
./osmfilter argentina-latest.osm --keep="highway=*" --drop-version > argentina-streets.osm

./osmconvert64 argentina-streets.osm --all-to-nodes --csv="@id @lat @lon highway name" > argentina-streets.csv
```

This should get you a spreadsheet that you should find easier to filter.